# Error with JAX-WS Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '['

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, webservice-client

It´s showing the following error and I have not idea why, can someone help me?

The error is:

> Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '['
>   (code 91) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]

The function I´m making the call is:

```
private static ContractTermsDownloadReply contractTermsDownloadOperation(
        ContractTermsDownloadRequest body) {
    ContractTermsDownload service = null;
    try {
        URI uri = new URI("https://companyname.com/ContractTermsDownload");
        service = new ContractTermsDownload(uri.toURL());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    ariba.sourcing.vrealm_1461.ContractTermsDownloadPortType port = service
            .getContractTermsDownloadPortType();
    BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
    prov.getRequestContext().put("authorization",
            "Basic User2011:Password2011");

    try {
        ContractTermsDownloadReply reply = port
                .contractTermsDownloadOperation(body);
        return reply;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to use the [CFX](http://cxf.apache.org/) library and it worked fine, the code is this:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(contractTermsDownloadPortType);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor(Phase.MARSHAL) {

        public void handleFault(Message message) {
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
            MetadataMap<String, Object> headers = new MetadataMap<String, Object>();
            headers.putSingle("authorization", "Basic User:Password2012");
            message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help someone, because it was a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using BasicAuth, the credentials would usually be Base64 Encoded.  Please focus on this line, to include the syntax:

```
prov.getRequestContext().put("authorization", "Basic User2011:Password2011");
```